# Filtering and sorting an SQL query to recreate a nested struct

Tags: sql, json, sorting, go, struct

I am new to Go and I'm trying to populate a struct called **Reliefworker** from an SQL query which I can send as a JSON payload.

Essentially I have a Reliefworker who may be assigned to many communities and the community can consist of multiple regions.

I suspect there is a clever way of doing this other than what I intend which is a primitive solution that will add a sort to the SQL (by Community) and create a function that detects if the community being added is different to the previous one, in which case I would create a new community struct type object to be appended.

```
type Reliefworker struct {
    Name     string `json:"name"`
    Communities  []Community `json:"community"`
    Deployment_id    string `json:"deployment_id"`
 }

 type Community struct{
    Name     string `json:"name"`
    community_id     string `json:"community_id"`
    Regions []Region `json:"regions"`
}

type Region struct{
    Name     string `json:"name"`
    Region_id     string `json:"region_id"`
    Reconstruction_grant   string `json:"reconstruction_grant"`
    Currency string `json:"currency"`
}
```

Currently I have created a struct that reflects what I am actually getting from SQL whilst pondering my next move. Perhaps this might be a good stepping stone instead of attempting an on-the-fly transformation ?

```golang
type ReliefWorker_community_region struct {
    Deployment_id        string
    Community_title      int
    Region_name          string
    Reconstruction_grant int
}

func GetReliefWorkers(deployment_id string) []Reliefworker {

    fmt.Printf("Confirm I have a deployment id:%v\n", deployment_id)

    rows, err := middleware.Db.Query("select deployment_id, community_title, region_name, reconstruction_grant WHERE Deployment_id=$1", brand_id)

    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    for rows.Next() {
        reliefworker := Reliefworker{}
        err = rows.Scan(&deployment_id, &community_title, &region_name, &reconstruction_grant)
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
    }
    rows.Close()

    return
}
```

Comment: global state is not making it easy to read. In any case, There may be a method to load everything in one query but you can load this sequentially. I assume you have some notion of foreign key and one to many strategy. Load relief worker data, then load and parse all its communities and in the end for each community load its regions. Thus you have the struct constructed.

Comment: I appreciate the ideas albeit abstract. I'm not entirely sure how foreign keys help me as I am currently pulling everything from a single table. Are you suggesting I use simpler SQL tables in order to establish foreign key relationships that can help in building my nested go struct ? Its possible but I would need a little more meat on the bone with regard your idea. Also I am not wedded to having a global state if it makes things easier. My hunch is that there is a clean way to do this using map and slice functions with just a good smattering of a solid sorting function.

Comment: Perhaps it would be more apt to retitle this question "Marshalling an SQL result set into a nested Go struct" ? if so someone else may need to do it as I've been previously warned to re-titling a question in order to make it more apt.

Comment: Its probably just me having not enough knowledge about what you can do with some sql databases. If your approach does not duplicate any data then it is probably optimal one. If you want a clean way of unmarshaling database output into struct you should probably use some ORM. Though using orm isn't always the answer. From what I understand you should be able to modify the data in database directly, still working with nested structure instead of relational database is uncommon (to me). Advantage of having relations is that you have no duplicates and can easily add and remove items.

Comment: You've set me down the right path I believe. its probably not going to be pretty but I am working on something

Comment: we might have found you some solutions. Please report the debug : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a sort makes a lot of sense, primitive solutions can be the most efficient:

```golang
func GetReliefWorkers(deployment_id string) []Reliefworker {
    // Added sort to query
    q := "select worker_name, community_title, region_name, reconstruction_grant WHERE deployment_id=? ORDER BY community_title"    
    rows, err := middleware.Db.Query(q, deployment_id)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer rows.Close() // So rows get closed even on an error
    c := Community{} // To keep track of the current community
    cmatrix := [][]string{[]string{}}  // Matrix of communities and workers
    communities := []Community{} // List of communities
    workers := make(map[string]Reliefworker) // Map of workers
    var ccount int // Index of community in lists
    for rows.Next() {
        w := Reliefworker{Deployment_id: deployment_id}
        r := Region{}
        var ctitle string  // For comparison later
        err = rows.Scan(&w.Name, &ctitle, &r.Name, &r.Reconstruction_grant)
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
        if ctitle != c.Name {
            communities = append(communities, c)
            c = Community{}
            c.Name = ctitle
            ccount++
            cmatrix = append(cmatrix, []string{})
        }
        c.Regions = append(c.Regions, r)
        cmatrix[ccount] = append(cmatrix[ccount], w.Name)
        workers[w.Name] = w
    }
    for i, c := range communities {
        for _, id := range cmatrix[i] {
            w := workers[id] // To avoid error 
            w.Communities = append(w.Communities, c)
            workers[id] = w
        }
    }
    out := []Reliefworker{}
    for _, w := range workers {
        out = append(out, w)
    }
    return out
}
```

Though it might make even more sense to create seperate tables for communities, regions, and workers, then query them all with a `JOIN`: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

UPDATE: Since you only want to retrieve one `Reliefworker`, would something like this work?

```golang
type ReliefWorker struct {
    Name        string      `json:"name"`
    Communities []Community `json:"community"`
}

type Community struct {
    Name    string   `json:"name"`
    Regions []Region `json:"regions"`
}

type Region struct {
    Name                 string `json:"name"`
    Region_id            string `json:"region_id"`
    Reconstruction_grant int    `json:"reconstruction_grant"`
    Currency             string `json:"currency"`
}

func GetReliefWorkers(deployment_id string) Reliefworker {
    reliefworker := Reliefworker{}
    communities := make(map[string]Community)
    rows, err := middleware.Db.Query("select name, community_title, region_name, region_id, reconstruction_grant WHERE Deployment_id=$1", deployment_id)
    if err != nil {
        if err == sql.ErrNoRows {
            fmt.Printf("No records for ReliefWorker:%v\n", deployment_id)
        }
        panic(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    for rows.Next() {
        c := Community{}
        r := Region{}
        err = rows.Scan(&reliefworker.Name, &c.Name, &r.Name, &r.Region_id, &r.Reconstruction_grant)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        if _, ok := communities[c.Name]; ok {
            c = communities[c.Name]
        }
        c.Regions = append(c.Regions, r)
        communities[c.Name] = c
    }
    for _, c := range commmunities {
        reliefworker.Communities = append(reliefworker.Communities, c)
    }
    return reliefworker
}
```

Comment: if the sql rows contains an empty community title, i believe, something weird will happen because if will appear first then `ctitle != c.Name` will return false. no ?

Comment: and here `communities = append(communities, c)` it will append an empty community the first time the surrounding if statement is true.

Comment: Yes, it will append an empty object first if there's no blank community title, but that's fine, it will just skip past in the last loop.
Good point about a blank title though, I'll make an edit.

Comment: IDK, i tried to reason your code, it is painfully hard. for a while i thought using maps would be more appropriate.

Comment: I use a map for the workers. I'm sorry that it's painful, I'm just trying to help. Do you mean maps in place of structs?

Comment: Blank title is fine, the only value set it the loop is the title, so it doesn't matter that the if returns false, because `c.Name == ""`

Comment: I might just be tired.  i think it might use map[Community][]workersName{}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235431/discussion-between-absentbird-and-mh-cbon).

Comment: another version, greatly improved with help of Absentbird https://play.golang.org/p/fi8z_0xvkww thanks to him for reviewing and comments.

Comment: Thank you so much ! Lots to glean from this.  I currently get the error "cannot assign to struct field workers[id].Communities in mapcompilerUnaddressableFieldAssign" for the line  `workers[id].Communities = append(workers[id].Communities, c)`

Comment: Thanks mh-cbon, I really appreciate your efforts. This works well albeit without the following lines carried over lines that are unused: `cmatrix := [][]string{[]string{}}` and      
 `var ccount int // Index of community in lists`

Comment: I added a couple lines that should resolve the error.
`w := workers[id]`
`w.Communities = append(w.Communities, c)`
`workers[id] = w`
Adjusts the value as a variable, then reassigns it to the map.

Comment: Thank you, that works, concise and elegant !

Answer (score 1):

Ok, my crude solution doesn't contain a shred of the intelligence @Absentbird demonstrates but I'm here to learn.

@Absentbird I love your use of maps and multidimensional arrays to hold a matrix of communities and workers. I will focus on making this part of my arsenal over the weekend.

I can accept and adapt @Absentbird's solution once I have a solution to why it gives the error "cannot assign to struct field workers[id].Communities in mapcompilerUnaddressableFieldAssign" for the line `workers[id].Communities = append(workers[id].Communities, c)`

Firstly apologies as I had to correct two things. Firstly I only needed to return ReliefWorkers (not an array of ReliefWorkers). Secondly ReliefWorker struct did not need to contain the Deployment_id since I already knew it.

I am new to Go so I'd really appreciate feedback on what I can do to better leverage the language and write more concise code.

My structs and solution is currently as follows:

```
type ReliefWorker struct {
    Name        string      `json:"name"`
    Communities []Community `json:"community"`
}

type Community struct {
    Name    string   `json:"name"`
    Regions []Region `json:"regions"`
}

type Region struct {
    Name      string `json:"name"`
    Region_id string `json:"region_id"`
    Reconstruction_grant        int    `json:"reconstruction_grant"`
    Currency  string `json:"currency"`
}

type ReliefWorker_community_region struct {
    Name    string
    Community_title string
    Region_name     string
    Reconstruction_grant  int
}

func GetReliefWorkers(deployment_id string) Reliefworker {

    var reliefworker Reliefworker
    var communitiesOnly []string
    var name string
    var allReliefWorkerData []ReliefWorker_community_region
    rows, err := middleware.Db.Query("select name, community_title, region_name, reconstruction_grant WHERE Deployment_id=$1", deployment_id)

    for rows.Next() {
        reliefWorker_community_region := ReliefWorker_community_region{}
        err = rows.Scan(&reliefWorker_community_region.Name, &reliefWorker_community_region.Community_title, &reliefWorker_community_region.Region_name, &reliefWorker_community_region.Reconstruction_grant)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        name = reliefWorker_community_region.Name
        allReliefWorkerData = append(allReliefWorkerData, reliefWorker_community_region)
        communitiesOnly = append(communitiesOnly, reliefWorker_community_region.Community_title)  //All communities go in here, even duplicates, will will create a unique set later
    }
    rows.Close()

    if err != nil {
        if err == sql.ErrNoRows {
            fmt.Printf("No records for ReliefWorker:%v\n", deployment_id)
        }
        panic(err)
    }

    var unique []string  //Use this to create a unique index of communities

    for _, v := range communitiesOnly {
        skip := false
        for _, u := range unique {
            if v == u {
                skip = true
                break
            }
        }
        if !skip {
            unique = append(unique, v)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(unique)

    reliefworker.Name = name
    var community Community
    var communities []Community

    for _, v := range unique {
        community.Name = v
        communities = append(communities, community)
    }


// Go through each record from the database held within allReliefWorkerData and grab every region belonging to a Community, when done append it to Communities and finally append that to ReliefWorker

    for j, u := range communities {
        var regions []Region

        for i, v := range allReliefWorkerData {

            if v.Community_title == u.Name {
                var region Region
                region.Name = v.Region_name
                region.Reconstruction_grant = v.Reconstruction_grant
                regions = append(regions, region)
            }
        }
        communities[j].Regions = regions

    }
    reliefworker.Communities = communities
    return reliefworker
}
```

Comment: I believe I've resolved the error in my solution with an update.

Comment: If it's all going into one reliefworker object, would this work? https://play.golang.org/p/Qidlk6_msGb

Comment: I've edited an improved variation into my original answer.